# Only Send an Email if Specific Cells are not empty

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code, but I also want a test that prevents me from sending an email if Cells B20 and B21 are empty.

```
Sub Send_Range_Or_Whole_Worksheet_with_MailEnvelope()
    'Working in Excel 2002-2016
    Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Fill in the Worksheet/range you want to mail
    'Note: if you use one cell it will send the whole worksheet
    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B21")

    'Remember the activesheet
    Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet

    With Sendrng

        ' Select the worksheet with the range you want to send
        .Parent.Select

        'Remember the ActiveCell on that worksheet
        Set rng = ActiveCell

        'Select the range you want to mail
        .Select

        ' Create the mail and send it
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope

            ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
            ' some header text to the email body.
            .Introduction = "Please see Quality Review Sev 1 details below."

            With .Item
                .To = "danielle.a.ext@razer.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = Range("E2").Value
                .send

            End With

        End With
        
        MsgBox "Email Sent"

        'select the original ActiveCell
        rng.Select
    End With

    'Activate the sheet that was active before you run the macro
    AWorksheet.Select

    StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Test for the condition and use `Exit Sub` to end the sub routine.

> ```
> If Len(Range("B20").Value) = 0 Or Len(Range("B21").Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub
> ```

Comment: Which part should I insert that one sir? Thank you in advance?

Comment: You would want it as the first line of the sub. In this way you would immediately exit the sub, if the conditions weren't met.

Comment: Thank you for that one, what if I want to add like a message telling that "Please complete the form"

This is the code right?   MsgBox "Please Complete form" and is it possible?

Comment: @DanielleAlmodiel Yes, it is possible.  I recommend watching the WiseOwl VBA tutorials on YouTube.  Here is the relavent one: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 10 - Message Boxes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JF1ZLOczSvw)